# Bilinear form vs two-form

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

I have a basic linear algebra question since I'm confused with the definitions:

*What is the difference between bilinear form and 2-form*?

I looked up in Wikipedia and it says that a linear form $B(v,w)$ can be symmetric or antisymmetric. For a 2-form $\omega(X,Y)$, it has to be antisymmetric per definition. Is it the only difference?

I apologise if the question is too basic. The problem is, I don't know much about the wedge products so I would appreciate if someone could explain the 2-forms maybe with them? From what I understand, given a basis, 2-form is just a matrix?

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multilinear k-form on an $F$-vector space $V$ is just a function from $V^k$ to $F$ which is linear in each component. These can be symmetric, alternating, or neither. Here, a bilinear form and a two-form are the same thing. In $\Bbb(R)^n$, a bilinear form can be represented by a nxn matrix, based on how it treats the basis elements.

A differential k-form is something completely different. They can be defined as a continuous map from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $A^k(n)$, the set of all alternating multilinear k-forms (as defined above) in $\Bbb{R}^n$. A differential 2-form would never be called a "bilinear form."

Finally, the wedge product is a product of alternating multilinear forms (say, $k$- and $l$- forms) which returns an alternating multilinear $k+l$-form. This product satisfies associative and distributive laws with addition; if $kl$ is even, then it's commutative, and it's anti-commutative otherwise. As an example, let $\omega_1 = f \space dx + g \space dy$ and $\omega_2 = h \space dx + i \space dy$ be 1-forms in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Then
$$\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 = fh \space dx \wedge dx + gi \space dy \wedge dy + fi \space dx \wedge dy + gh \space dy \wedge dx = (fi - gh)\space dx \wedge dy$$
which is a 2-form.

Comment: @AhmedHussein My mistake, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still a bit confused. The statement where I came across it was "Let $\omega$ be a non-degenerate 2-form on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$...", and then along the lines it was used (after picking a basis) that the matrix for $\omega$ is skew-symmetric. So, is skew-symmetry then always automatically implied or not? Also, is 2-form always a matrix?

Comment: @GregVoit I don't have the full context, but it seems to be talking about a differential form. So, if you evaluate $\omega$ at a point in $\Bbb{R}^4$, you get a alternating (and in this case, non-degenerate) bilinear form on  $\Bbb{R}^4$; so at each point, $\omega$ can be represented with a 4x4 skew-symmetric matrix.

Comment: I see, thank you. Last question: when you say "evaluate $\omega$ at a point in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$", you mean computing $\omega(X,Y)$ for two vectors $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^{4}$ right? How do I carry out this computation explicitly using your definition above? (like I said, I don't know much about wedge products) Could you give a short sample calculation?

Comment: @GregVoit So, the definition I gave above says that a differential k-form is a continuous function from $\Bbb{R}^4$ to $A^k(n)$. So, in other words, you evaluate $\omega$ at a point in $\Bbb{R}^4$, and what you get is an alternating bilinear form on $\Bbb{R}^4$. I'll give an explicit example in my next comment.

Comment: @GregVoit Say you have the 2-form in $\Bbb{R}^4$ $\omega = x_3\space dx_1 \wedge dx_2$. Then if we let $p = (1, 2, 3, 4)$, we have $\omega(p) = 3 \space dx_1 \wedge dx_2$, which represents three times the alternating 2-form corresponding to {1, 2}. (hopefully you've gone over the basis elements of $A^k(n)$). Anyway, you won't really need to worry about actually evaluating the alternating forms given by differential forms; most of what you do will be based on the computational properties for the wedge product, pullback, etc. So just get an intuition for how they behave.

Comment: hm, but for a 2-form we need two arguments, i.e. $\omega(p,q)$. At least in my example then it always appears with two arguments

Comment: Given a point $p$ in $\Bbb{R}^4$, $\omega(p)$ is itself an alternating bilinear form; evaluating it would look something like $\omega(p)(x, y)$ where $x, y$ are in $\Bbb{R}^4$. $\omega$ isn't itself a multilinear form; it gives you back a multilinear form when you give it a point in $\Bbb{R}^4$.

Comment: ah, ok, but what is then $\omega(p)(x,y)$? That is, how do I see that it's a matrix? By your example above, $\omega(p)(X,Y)=3 dx_{1}\wedge dx_{2} (X,Y)$. Is that a matrix?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41545/discussion-between-florence-and-gregvoit).